# How to substruct some table rows from another related table rows and get the SUM of the totale result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-key, sum

I have two table (Orders, Payments)
they are 1 to many relationships (1:N)
One order can have many payments

Table 1: **Orders**

| id | total_price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2000 |
| 3 | 3000 |

Table 2: **Payments**

| order_id(FK of Orders) | amount_payed |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 2000 |
| 3 | 1000 |
| 3 | 500 |
| 3 | 750 |

some orders are not totally payed, so **I wanna get**

1- the rest paid of each order .. Like :

| order | rest payed |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 |
| 3 | 750 |

2- the sum of the rest of all the orders Like:
1250

And Thank you.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: I didn't even know where to start with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, I did the following (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/IbGt1E5x)):

```
CREATE TABLE _order
(
  order_id    INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  total_price INT NOT NULL
);
```

populate:

```
INSERT INTO _order VALUES
(1, 1000), (2, 2000), (3, 3000);
```

I used `_order` for the table name instead of `orders` because I don't like plural table names - a table is a set and should have a singular name. It may contain 0, 1 or many records - not necessarily many. I also use snake_case for table names. These are just a personal things - choose a convention and stick to it!

Then:

```
CREATE TABLE payment
(
  order_id INT NOT NULL,
  amount   INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT payment_order_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES _order (order_id)
);
```

and:

```
INSERT INTO payment VALUES
(1, 500), (2, 2000), (3, 1000), (3, 500), (3, 750);
```

and run the following SQL:

```
SELECT
  o.order_id, o.total_price, t.order_id, t.sum_pay, o.total_price - t.sum_pay AS owed
FROM
  _order o
JOIN
(
  SELECT
    order_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_pay
  FROM
    payment
  GROUP BY order_id
) AS t
ON o.order_id = t.order_id
ORDER BY o.order_id;
```

Result:

```
order_id total_price order_id sum_pay   owed
       1        1000        1     500    500
       2        2000        2    2000      0
       3        3000        3    2250    750
```

I left the extra fields in there so that you can see what's going on. We can clean this up as follows to give your desired result:

```
SELECT
  o.order_id AS o_id, o.total_price - t.sum_pay AS owed
FROM
  _order o
JOIN
(
  SELECT
    order_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_pay
  FROM
    payment
  GROUP BY order_id
) AS t
ON o.order_id = t.order_id
WHERE o.total_price - t.sum_pay != 0
ORDER BY o.order_id;
```

Result:

```
o_id    owed
   1     500
   3     750
```

and to get the overall sum of what's owed for **every** order, we do the following:

```
SELECT
  SUM(owed) AS total_owed_all_orders
FROM
(  
  SELECT
    o.order_id AS o_id, o.total_price - t.sum_pay AS owed
  FROM
    _order o
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      order_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_pay
    FROM
      payment
    GROUP BY order_id
  ) AS t
  ON o.order_id = t.order_id
  WHERE o.total_price - t.sum_pay != 0
) AS t2;
```

Result:

```
total_owed_all_orders
                 1250
```

Et voilà - results as requested.

You might also want to try something like the following if you wish to avoid too many subselects - and you get all of your desired data in one go, so to speak.

```
SELECT
  o.order_id AS o_id, o.total_price - t.sum_pay AS owed, SUM(o.total_price - t.sum_pay) OVER () AS tot_owed
FROM
  _order o
JOIN
(
  SELECT
    order_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_pay
  FROM
    payment
  GROUP BY order_id
) AS t
ON o.order_id = t.order_id
WHERE o.total_price - t.sum_pay != 0
ORDER BY o.order_id;
```

Result:

```
o_id    owed    tot_owed
   1     500        1250
   3     750        1250
```

[Window functions](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/introduction-to-t-sql-window-functions/) are well worth getting to know as they are **very** powerful and will repay any effort spent learning them many times over! The best presentation I've ever seen about them is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8Q4n6YXdpk) by Bruce Momjian (a PostgreSQL core team member) - it's about PostgreSQL, but the same basics will apply. Other presentations by him available [here](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=bruce%20momjian%20window%20functions).

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` and `ISNULL` might be wise, in case there are no payments at all

Comment: Thank you so much for all the great explaination and the resources
I usually use the singular name to name my tables but this time just not to mix it with Order, but I liked your naming_convention 
And also in my case I had a very big number so I filterd it by the validtion date i added 
AND O.Validated_at BETWEEN '2022-10-01 06:53:02.000' AND '2022-10-12 06:53:02.000'
before the last line, thank you again and I would like to suggest me a great book or more videos to be as great as you're

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using an `APPLY` subquery.

Note that `OUTER APPLY` works like a left-join (as opposed to `CROSS APPLY`) and will give you `Orders` even if there are no `Payments` at all for it.

```sql
SELECT
  o.id,
  remaining = o.total_price - ISNULL(p.payed, 0)
FROM Orders o
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT payed = SUM(p.amount_payed)
    FROM Payments p
    WHERE p.order_id = o.id
) p
WHERE o.total_price > ISNULL(p.payed, 0);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Uqrr0hUo)